# join two streams based on common field in storm bolt

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

Problem Statement: 
I would like to join two Streams from two different Kafka Spouts (say S1 and S2) and want to join the tuples from each stream based on some common field in them.
if "S1" recieves below json as a tuple

```
{"l7ProtocolID":"dhcp",
"packets_out":1,
"bytes_out":400,
"start_time":1454281199898,
"flow_sample":0,
"duration":102,
"path":["base","ip","udp","dhcp"],
"bytes_in":1200,
"l4":[{"client":"68","server":"67","level":0}],
"l2":[{"client":"52:54:00:50:04:B2","server":"FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF","level":0}],
"l3":[{"client":"::ffff:0.0.0.0","server":"::ffff:255.255.255.255","level":0}],
"flow_id":"81454281200000731489",
"applicationID":"dhcp",
"packets_in":1}
```

and "S2" recieves below JSON as tuple

```
{"portGroupName":"dhcp",
"hypervisorName":1,
"bytes_out":400,
"monitoredIP":1454281199898,
"monitoredInstance":0,
"duration":102,
"bytes_in":1200,
"flow_id":"81454281200000731489",
"tenant":1}
```

I would like to join both based on a common field say, "flow_id" here in case.
Suggest Example or Approach. Confused with .fieldsGrouping, Is that a solution to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tident API to do a join:

```java
TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
// do some stuff here
topology.join(stream1, new Fields("key"), stream2, new Fields("x"), new Fields("key", "a", "b", "c"));
```

See documenation for more details: https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Trident-API-Overview.html

If you want to use low-level API, using `fieldsGrouping` would be correct (of course, you need to think about "windowing" by yourself)

Something like this:

```java
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("spout1",...);
builder.setSpout("spout2",...);

builder.setSpout("join",...)
       .fieldsGrouping("spout1", new Fields("flow_id"))
       .fieldsGrouping("spout2", new Fields("flow_id"));
```